# cross domain request issue origin not allow

Tags: ajax

cross domain request issue

my ajax call code actually when i am running given url directly in browser it shows me json data but using ajax call it always shows me ajax error believe me i tried n follow many things no fruitful result from 18 days.

```
$.ajax({
        crossDomain:true,
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://taxihub.azurewebsites.net/Mobile/api/json.php?method=getCompanyList',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        success: function (data) {

                console.log(data);
                return;

        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log("AJAX ERROR");
            console.log(err.responseText);
        }
    });
```

you can also check this link directly u will see json data coming but i found error i dont know why 
"http://taxihub.azurewebsites.net/Mobile/api/json.php?method=getCompanyList"

error: OPTIONS http://taxihub.azurewebsites.net/Mobile/api/json.php?method=getCompanyList Origin lhost:809 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

please help me i am stuck here from 18 days on this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `cross-domain` and `content-type` part and it'll work but you'll have to do a little extra string manipulation work to put it in JSON object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://taxihub.azurewebsites.net/Mobile/api/json.php?method=getCompanyList',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.result.getCompanyList[0].CompanyID);
            return;
    },
    error: function (err) {
        console.log("AJAX ERROR");
        console.log(err);
    }
});
}
```

Actually it seems cross-domain doesn't have any effect with or without it. I guess the server you're targeting doesn't have strict cross-domain prevention but doesn't like the JSON content-type. I'd be glad to get a more specific explanation.

**EDIT** I used JQuery 1.10.2 if it matters

Comment: JScoobyCed this works for me but still one problem data recieve but when response come means data so i am calling data.result.getcompanylist its accessible when i am debuging just showing me data

Comment: {"result":{"getCompanyList":[{"CompanyID":"1","Email":"wajih@thefastmarket.com","Company":"TheFastMarket","LogoPath":"logo.jpg"},{"CompanyID":"2","Email":"farhan@hotmail.com","Company":"Hotmail","LogoPath":"logo1.jpg"},{"CompanyID":"3","Email":"omair@yahoo.com","Company":"Yahoo","LogoPath":"logo2.jpg"},{"CompanyID":"1001","Email":"gillani.omair@gmail.com","Company":"\\\\icon","LogoPath":"Dubai Taxi"}]}, "error":[]}

Comment: in data there is object but its when i am writing to access its values like data.result.getCompanyList[0].CompanyID its undefined showing

Comment: thanx alot JScoobyCed finally done sucessfully thanx alot after 18 days problem solved

Comment: thnx alot  JScoobyCed